# Why is request method send to web server called GET and POST?

Tags: http, terminology

I guessed that the name of each of the request method has a relationship with the operations they performed in some manner. But I can't get it!

**Detials:** 
GET means posted argument are showed in the url and POST means they are sent but not shown in the url. But what is that related to POST/GET? What is gotten/posted or what does the posting/getting job? Do you have any glues?

I understand what GET and POST method is. What I wanna know is why do we GET/POST, why don't we call it TYPE1/TYPE2, or another more make-sense name like ON-URL/OFF-URL

Please discuss if you know that.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

**Methods GET and POST in HTML forms - what's the difference?** 
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

**The Definitive Guide to GET vs POST**
http://carsonified.com/blog/dev/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post/

**get and post**
http://catcode.com/formguide/getpost.html

Answer (score 1):

From [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html):

**GET**

> The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI.

**POST**

> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line.

So, **GET** should be used to **read** a resource, whereas **POST** should be used to **create**, **update**, or **delete** a resource.

Comment: I understand what GET and POST method is. What I wanna know is why do we call it GET/POST, why don't we call it TYPE1/TYPE2, or another more make name like URLGET/NONURLGET

Answer (score 1):

GET and POST are called HTTP Verbs. See the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) for details.

GET will get a resource identified by a URL. If using GET as the action for a form the entries will be encoded in the URL (look at a google search for an example).

POST will send the data separately, to the specified URL.

The biggest difference is that if you use GET on a form submit, you can copy the URL of the page you landed at and use it directly to get the same results. All information will also be visible in the URL (don't use this method for passwords). If you POST the data the URL of the landing page will not be enough to reproduce the same results; you will have to go through the form again.

Comment: I understand what GET and POST method is. What I wanna know is why do we call it GET/POST, why don't we call it TYPE1/TYPE2, or another more make name like URLGET/NONURLGET.

Comment: Well I suppose these particular verbs were chosen because they describe the operation in the fewest characters.

Comment: @David Grant: You're the one who most understand my question :) Though, I've update my questions to make it clearer. Still want to know how near the GET/POST is to their operation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the RFC definitions here:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

But essentially, GET is used to retrieve a resource and POST is used to create a new one or make a change to a resource.

Comment: I understand what GET and POST method is. What I wanna know is why do we call it GET/POST, why don't we call it TYPE1/TYPE2, or another more make name like URLGET/NONURLGET

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that @Nam G. VU is asking an English-language question.

**"Get"** implies that the flow of data is from the server to the client. More specifically, the client is asking the server to send some data.

**"Post"** implies that the client is pushing data to the server. The word "post" implies that it's a one-way operation.

Of course, neither of these is 100% unidirectional: GETs can send data to the server in the 
URL as path and/or query arguments, and POSTS return data to the client.

But, in the simplest sense, the English verbs imply the principal direction of data flow.

Answer (score 0):

From the REST standpoint, GET METHOD signifies that it is used to GET a (list of similar) resource(s). POST is used to create (or POST) a resource.

Apart from this, GET carries all parameters in the URL in the format of `?name=value&` pairs, whereas POST carries all of them in the Request Body.

Comment: It is very interesting @asgs. Would be lovely to have some reference/url for `From the REST standpoint`

Comment: The [REST Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) should help you understand this further, especially the [RESTful_web_services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) section.